# Re-order a table in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a table in R and I have data like these:

```
ID    month_yr     trt 
1      7-2020       A 
2      2-2021       A 
3      12-2021      C
4      2-2021       B
5      2-2021       C
6      7-2020       A
```

I would like to make a table in R, and I know how to do:

```
table(df$month_yr,df$trt)
```

It is giving this output:

```
            A       B       C 

2-2021      1       1       1
7-2020      2       0       0
12-2021     0       0       1
```

I would like to have the dates in sequential order in the table. I have tried using the lubridate package to change them to a date format. I also think it might be possible to set the order manually with "levels" but I'm not sure how to do that with a table. I am fairly new to R and just need some help getting the correct code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may change it to `Date` class or `yearmon` class from `zoo` i..e `table(zoo::as.yearmon(df$month_yr, "%m-%Y"), df$tr)`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
  month_yr = c("7-2020","2-2021",
               "12-2021","2-2021","2-2021","7-2020"),
  trt = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A")
)

table(my(df$month_yr) %>% as.character %>% str_remove("-\\d+$"), df$tr)

#>          
#>           A B C
#>   2020-07 2 0 0
#>   2021-02 1 1 1
#>   2021-12 0 0 1
```